# Expanding an alpha-numeric string in an Excel cell into comma separated individual alpha-numerics

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am looking for a way of taking a cell that contains a string such as "C365-C370" into a cell that contains that range spread out and separated by either a space or a comma, like "C365, C366, C367, C368, C369, C370".

Or perhaps, more complicated, taking a cell that has a mix of individual alpha-numerics containing a range, like "C362, C365-C370, C374, C382" into a cell that contains these spread out and separated by either a space or a comma, like "C362 C365 C366 C367 C368 C369 C370 C374 C382".

Comment: Find "-" replace with " "?   Or, in VBA `Cells.Replace What:="-", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False`

Answer (score 0):

Select cells that contain data like:

```
C100-C110
```

and run this simple macro:

```
Sub SpreadThem()
    Dim r As Range, N1 As Long, N2 As Long, i As Long
    Dim st As String, CH As String
    For Each r In Selection
        If InStr(r.Text, "-") > 0 Then
            ary = Split(r.Text, "-")
            N1 = Mid(ary(0), 2)
            N2 = Mid(ary(1), 2)
            CH = Left(ary(0), 1)
            For i = N1 To N2
                st = st & "," & CH & i
            Next i
            st = Mid(st, 2)
            r.Value = st
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

The contents will change to:

```
C100,C101,C102,C103,C104,C105,C106,C107,C108,C109,C110
```